# How to notify a caller of the HTTP post method upon request completion in REST

Tags: web-services, rest, post

I am implementing a REST webservice and I have a resource (http://localhost/createUser) which is a POST method and takes in a JSON user object.

Now at time t1, a caller calls this API with a JSON object. I make basic validations at time t1 and return response as sucessfull.

But at my backend, this person creation logic takes a while to "really create" and persist it to database - which will take some time - say at time t2 - the user creation is completed.

Now what are the ways for me to notify the caller that this User Creation has been "really successfull"? (or the user creation might fail in between t1 and t2, how to notify this to the caller of this API? what are the ways?)

One way I think of is, create a requestId for each such request and the caller keeps polling another GET API, like (http://localhost/status/requestId) which will give him the result for that request.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either wait for the user to "really" be created before returning or implement a getUser-like operation... which may have a status field for "creating" vs "created". Mapping every call to a "requestId" seems like a bit much, in my opinion.

Comment: In my case, the user creation and persistence to database may take arbitrary time. It might take more than 5mins depending on the load on the server. Won't I get a timeout exception or something if I am waiting till time "t2" which is the real completion ?

Comment: Ahh, if it's on the order of minutes, then I see your need.

Comment: @@Kiran There are ways to extend timeouts, but you almost certainly want to go with your second idea - respond to the user immediately saying creation underway, then where it fits in with the client-workflow (or polling) determine that the create succeeded / failed.

Comment: Now, I have one more doubt. If my http://localhost/createUser API is being called very rapidly to create Users. I don't think I can afford to create as many requestIDs and keep track of them. Can some sort of Queues be imeplememnted? (Just a thought.. didnt think through this yet..)

Comment: However you handle that, it should be done in a thread-safe way. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html for thread-safe collections.